# Algorithm for converting fraction into (recurring) decimal

Tags: fractions

I need to determine whether fraction is recurring decimal or not (what are conditions for it?), find period and output it as $\frac{1}{3}=0.\bar{3}$.

If it is not recurring, then I already have algorithm.

Comment: The algorithm always outputs, True. Should it also output the decimal?

Comment: All rational numbers (fractions of integers) have a decimal expansion that is repeating from some point on and vice versa. Example: $12.345\overline {678} = 4111111/333000$.

Comment: Long division is an algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if you have a repeating decimal
$$n=0.\overline{D_1D_2...D_k}$$
where each $D_i$ is a digit, you can say that
$$10^k n=D_1D_2...D_k.\overline{D_1D_2...D_k}$$
and so
$$10^k n-n=D_1D_2...D_k$$
and
$$n=\frac{D_1D_2...D_k}{10^k-1}$$
This means that $n$ can only be a repeating decimal if $n$ can be expressed in the form
$$n=\frac{a}{10^b-1}$$
and so if you are given a number in the form 
$$I+\frac{h}{j}$$
Where $I$ is an integer and $j\gt h$, then it can only be a repeating decimal if $j$ evenly divides $10^k-1$ for some $k$. For example, for $j=1,2,5,10$ it will never be a repeating decimal.

Does this help?